# Importing multiple csv files with read_csv in r

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, loading, readr

I have a vector with the names of multiple csv files.

```
library(readr)
data<-c("categories.csv",
    "customers.csv",
    "employees.csv",
    "employee_territories.csv",
    "order_details.csv",
    "orders.csv",
    "products.csv",
    "regions.csv",
    "shippers.csv",
    "suppliers.csv", 
    "territories.csv")
```

and I would like to load all of them with a `for` loop in my workspace.

My first try was

```
i<-1
for (i in data) {
  read_csv(data("i"))
}
```

maybe someone can help me.

Comment: In your code, `i` is file name, not file name index. You could try: `read_csv(i)`. Alternatively, use `for (i in seq(length(data))) { read_csv(data[i]) }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
out_list <- map(data, read_csv)
names(out_list) <- sub("\\.csv", "", data)
list2env(out_list, .GlobalEnv) # not recommended
```

---

Or using a `for` loop, create a NULL `list` to store the output of the read data, then loop over the 'data', read them and assign it to the output list element

```
out_list <- vector('list', length(data))
names(out_list) <- data
for(file in data) out_list[[file]] <- read_csv(file)
```

If we want to create multiple new objects (not recommended)

```
for(file in data) {
    assign(sub("\\.csv", "", file), read_csv(file))
 }
```

Comment: Now I have every csv file in one list. is it possible to have every dataset as a single csv file?

Comment: @YannikSacherer what would be the name of each object.  Is it without the `.csv`

Comment: @YannikSacherer i updated with `list2env` but it is not recommended though